# Which datatype should I use to store Days hours and minutes in milliseconds?

Tags: mysql

I want 3 columns, days, hours and minutes. I want them to be stored as milliseconds, which datatype should I use?

Answer (score 0):

`TIMESTAMP` is an option.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```